# Checking bits in a byte using for loop

Tags: c#

I was recently studying C# where i came across following for loop

```
// Display the bits within a byte.
using System;

class ShowBits { 

 static void Main() { 

  int t;
  byte val;
  val = 123; 

  for(t=128; t > 0; t = t/2) { 

     if((val & t) != 0)
         Console.Write("1 ");

     if((val & t) == 0) 
         Console.Write("0 ");

   }
 }
}
```

I am not able to understand that Why in doing t=t/2 in the incrementing/decrementing  section of the for loop . plz explain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's looping in decreasing powers of two and using that value in a mask.

(base 10): 128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1

(base 2):  10000000, 01000000, 00100000, 00010000, 00001000, 00000100, 00000010, 00000001

Answer (score 5):

Decimal 128 is binary 10000000 - i.e. a mask for just the most significant bit of the byte. When you divide it by two, you get 01000000, i.e. the *second* most significant bit, etc.

Using `&` between the original value and the mask and just comparing with 0 indicates whether that bit is set in the original value.

Another alternative would be to shift the original value instead:

```
for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--)
{
    int shifted = val >> i;
    // Take the bottom-most bit of the shifted value
    Console.Write("{0} ", shifted & 1);
}
```

Comment: @MitchWheat: Cheers - I could have sworn I'd put in 7 zeroes :)

Answer (score 3):

The t is used as a mask for the bits in `val`.
So it starts at 128, 10000000 in binary.
When it is divided by 2, it becomes 64 - or 01000000.
This goes until it reaches 0.

Then in each iteration, the '&' is used to mask the bits in `val` with the current bit in `t`.

Answer (score 3):

128 is written as `10000000` in binary, so we check if the highest bit in a byte is on. Then we do t=t/2, which is `t=128/2=64` which written as `01000000` in binary and so on. Any division shifts the one bit that is on one place to the right.